# C program fails at fopen, stack trace attached

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel, malloc, fopen

We have ported an application to run on Linux  with kernel 4.10.1. The program fails seems to hang at the __GI_abort() call, later a SIGABRT was issued against the process at which it again failed to write an error log file. This same program runs on Linux kernel 2.6. The stack trace and code are attached. Any suggestions would help. Thanks.

We had earlier built both the 4.10.1 kernel and application using gcc 6.3.1
The application has been compiled with :
gcc version 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1) (GCC)

stack trace:

```
(gdb) where
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
#1  0x00007f8f1c16ffb2 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=140252631706336, bytes@entry=552) at malloc.c:2923
#2  0x00007f8f1c15905d in __fopen_internal (filename=0x7ffeb54deac0 "/tmp/logs/app_exit.log", mode=0x497fc2 "a+", is32=1) at iofopen.c:69
#3  0x0000000000477690 in fep_sigbus_handler (signum=6, info=0x7ffeb54decb0, ptr=0x7ffeb54deb80) at app_util.c:559
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:58
#6  0x00007f8f1c12151a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#7  0x00007f8f1c169d68 in __malloc_assert (
    assertion=assertion@entry=0x7f8f1c277f90 "(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)", file=file@entry=0x7f8f1c274807 "malloc.c", line=line@entry=2403,
    function=function@entry=0x7f8f1c2787d8 <__func__.11266> "sysmalloc") at malloc.c:301
#8  0x00007f8f1c16d5b6 in sysmalloc (nb=nb@entry=560, av=0x7f8f1c4aaae0 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:2400
#9  0x00007f8f1c16e63a in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7f8f1c4aaae0 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=552) at malloc.c:3862
#10 0x00007f8f1c16ff14 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=552) at malloc.c:2925
#11 0x00007f8f1c15905d in __fopen_internal (filename=0xf4cda4 <file_tbl+4> "/etc/app_config.dat", mode=0x48b735 "r", is32=1)
    at iofopen.c:69
#12 0x000000000042e96c in load_conversion_file (filename=0xf4cda4 <file_tbl+4> "/etc/app_config.dat") at app_config.c:1817
#13 0x000000000042ebc2 in load_all_conversion_files () at app_config.c:1864
#14 0x000000000042eeb9 in app_config_init () at app_config.c:1958
#15 0x0000000000403d9e in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffeb54df6e8) at app_main.c:271

static int load_conversion_file( const char* filename )
{
    int     rc = FAILURE;
    FILE*   fd = NULL;
    int     parsedbg = (app_debug_mask & APP_DBG_PARSECONV) ? 1 : 0;
    AppCfg* pcfg;

    pcfg = (AppCfg*) malloc( sizeof(AppCfg) );

    if ( pcfg == NULL )
        LOG(APP_DBG_ERROR, BLANK_TID, ( "error allocating AppCfg\n" ));

    else if ( (fd = fopen( filename, "r" )) == NULL )
        LOG(APP_DBG_CONFIG, BLANK_TID, ( "error opening conversion file: %s\n",
                                              filename ) );

    else if ( app_parse_file( fd, pcfg, parsedbg ) != 0 )
        LOG(APP_DBG_CONFIG, BLANK_TID, ( "Parser error %s on line %d at token <%s>\n",
                                              app_parser_get_error_string(),
                                              app_parser_get_error_line(),
                                              app_parser_get_error_token() ) );
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you have a heap corruption somewhere else in the code. Try running it with valgrind to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a calloc() memory allocation in one of the functions, and this function was called prior to the fopen(). That function had code that populated the buffer calloced and also went past the last entry. After fixing that, the issue is resolved. However, the code in a prior version of linux, that was built with older version of gcc did not assert and abort at the malloc().

Comment: Different library versions do things differently. Why else would they have new versions? The newer allocator is likely better with multiple threads, less memory fragmentation, etc. It just happens to fail when you do things wrong.